can not able to get authorize code from webex service
I am building API to get the authorize code from webex.
I've a experience API (http://localhost:8081/captures/query) from where I am invoking system API ( http://localhost:8081/authorize) and from system API I am invoking OAuth Authorization URL.
When I am triggering http://localhost:8081/captures/query in browser it is asking for username and password and then it is redirecting to the page where it is giving error:

No listener for endpoint: /idb/globalLogin.

Not sure how and why it's redirecting to http://localhost:8081/idb/globalLogin. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong anywhere.

issue:

experience API- http://localhost:8081/captures/query
system API- http://localhost:8081/authorize
webex OAuth Authorization URL: https://webexapis.com/v1/authorize?client_id=1234&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/captures/query&scope=meeting:recordings_read meeting:recordings_write spark:calls_read spark:kms spark:places_write spark:rooms_read
code:
exp API:
        <flow name="exp" doc:id="99420f1e-76b8-4aca-8ed7-4fc6b2279db7" >
                <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="5b63c7e2-1310-4cfb-b5db-e0bfb383233b" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/captures/query"/>
                <set-variable value='#[attributes.queryParams.code default ""]' doc:name="code" doc:id="8319a36e-1dcd-450f-b3d8-6359e3fff0e1" variableName="code" />
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="ff26275e-7b18-4f6c-9ae9-15308c6f96d5" message="#[vars.code]"/>
                <choice doc:name="Choice" doc:id="d544cdee-9272-4296-a8eb-65a78797402e" >
                    <when expression='vars.code ==""'>
                        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="authorize" doc:id="e729c048-c160-481f-939c-131d9afea4f5" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1" path="/authorize">
                </http:request>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise >
                        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="accesstoken" doc:id="1f59a999-1065-4123-b65d-7ccb4ddafeac" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1" path="/accesstoken">
                            <http:query-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
        ---
        {
            "code" : vars.code
        }]]]></http:query-params>
                        </http:request>
                    </otherwise>
                </choice>
            </flow>

system API:
        <flow name="get_authorize" doc:id="2c60da85-f3fc-433b-b45f-ce94d1664bbc" >
                <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="ba33fdab-f9c7-46cc-b65f-6e388936adcf" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/authorize"/>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="6f38f867-7315-42b0-b435-e7885229b9a8" message='authorize started'/>
                <ee:transform doc:name="queryParam" doc:id="89590b81-1043-4026-aca9-12983b4cd7e7" >
                    <ee:message >
                        <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[output application/java
        ---
        {
            "response_type" : "code",
            "client_id" : "1234",
            "redirect_uri" : "http://localhost:8081/captures/query",
            "scope" : "meeting:recordings_read spark:kms spark:rooms_read spark:calls_read meeting:recordings_write spark:places_write"
            //"state": "test1234"
        }]]></ee:set-payload>
                    </ee:message>
                </ee:transform>
                <http:request method="GET" doc:name="authorize" doc:id="34c4a0f4-64b6-4a7f-820d-aa730990af62" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/authorize">
                    <http:query-params><![CDATA[#[payload]]]></http:query-params>
                </http:request>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="6edc9ded-92b0-4a55-bc78-91fd779e6fc2" message="authorize end"/>
            </flow>


We can't help without more details. What are the configuration and flows? [edit] your question to add a [mre]. Use text, not images, for XML, logs, errors and be sure to use [code block] formatting so it is readable. For URLs too use some code format too.

Enable HTTP wire logging and debug the HTTP requests.
